# How can I make my output's print statement return the correct label and not the location of where that label is stored?

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv, class

I'm defining a function for a class that derives its values from a CSV file I have read in. The function is essentially finding the distance between the two cities based on the associated latitude and longitude values in that city's record.

```
class City:
    def __init__ (self, name, label, lat, lon, pop_dict):
        self.name = name
        self.label = label
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.pop_dict = pop_dict

    def printDistance(self, othercity):     
        lat_self = self.lat
        lat_othercity = othercity.lat
        lon_self = self.lon
        lon_othercity = othercity.lon
        lat1 = float(lat_self)
        lat2 = float(lat_othercity)
        lon1 = float(lon_self)
        lon2 = float(lon_othercity)
        radian_lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
        radian_lat2 = math.radians(lat2)
        radian_lon1 = math.radians(lon1)
        radian_lon2 = math.radians(lon2)
        AD = (math.acos(math.sin(radian_lat1) * math.sin(radian_lat2) + math.cos(radian_lat1) * math.cos(radian_lat2) * math.cos(radian_lon1 - radian_lon2)))
        print "The distance between", self, "and", othercity, "is", int((AD * 6300)), "kilometers."

print Cities[0].printDistance(Cities[1])
```

The function works as intended, however I am only able to input the index value of a city's location for where it is stored, not the city's names themselves. So for the example print statement above, I receive: `The distance between <__main__.City instance at 0x103128d40> and <__main__.City instance at 0x1031285f0> is 5783 kilometers.`

I would prefer for my statement to operate so that I could simply run: `print Cities[Tokyo].printDistance(Cities[Paris])` for example.

Comment: Could please be more clear about what you expect? What output of `printDistance` do you exepect? Where is defined `Cities` and `Tokyo`?

Comment: @viniciusjssouza Thanks to the previous response, I now receive the output I expect which is the city names in the print statement as opposed to their indexed location. What I want however is for my print statement to accept the actual city names as inputs, and not their index number.  For example, I have `print Cities[0].printDistance(Cities[20])`  at the moment which gives me the output statement I desire. But for this to work, the user would need to know what index in the CSV each individual city is. I would like a print statement that lets the print statement take city names, not indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `print "The distance between", self, "and", othercity, "is", int((AD * 6300)), "kilometers."` to `print "The distance between", self.name, "and", othercity.name, "is", int((AD * 6300)), "kilometers."` The print function should show the names of the cities.